# Probability of two rare events both happening in the first two weeks of the year

Tags: probability

Let's say that the historical record shows that an earthquake of magnitude 4 or higher hits Faultline City once a year. The record also shows that a traffic jam causing delays of 24 hours or more happens roughly once every 25 years. I'm trying to figure out the odds of a 24 hour plus traffic jam and a magnitude 4 earthquake both happening during the first two weeks of a given year.

*Note that there's likely some dependence of the traffic jam on the earthquake, as I'd imagine major earthquakes make traffic jams significantly more likely. My statistics knowledge isn't quite at the level of being able to account for that, but if you can, I'd definitely love to learn, but it's not necessary for the question.*

Here's how I approached this, but I get the strong sense it's not right:

$$P_{yr}(E) \textrm{ is the probability of an earthquake of magnitude 4+ hitting the city in a given year}$$

$$P_{2wk}(E) \textrm{ is the probability of an earthquake of magnitude 4+ hitting the city in a given two weeks}$$

$$P_{25yr}(T) \textrm{ is the probability of a 24 hour or greater traffic jam in the city in a given 25 year period}$$

$$P_{2wk}(T) \textrm{ is the probability of a 24 hour or greater traffic jam in the city in a given two weeks}$$

$$P_{2wk}(E) = \frac{P_{yr}(E)}{26} = \frac{1}{26}$$

$$P_{2wk}(T) = \frac{P_{25yr}(E)}{25 * 26} = \frac{1}{650}$$

Both of the above two lines bother me, because even though the *expected value* for the event period for major earthquakes and major traffic jams is 1 year and 25 years respectively, that doesn't mean that these events are guaranteed to occur in their respective periods, and I don't know how to account for that. The above assumes 100% chance of the event happening during the period, which is just plain wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. Moving on...

$$P_{2wk}(E\cap T) = P_{2wk}(E) * P_{2wk}(T) = \frac{1}{26} * \frac{1}{650} = \frac{1}{16900} \approx 0.006\%$$

This assumes independence, and I'm not sure if I combined these correctly. I may have wanted to use binomial probability, but I don't really care whether these events happen again during the rest of the year, just during the first two weeks.

Please feel free to "rip me a new one" as far as my statistics are concerned. I'm here to learn, not to protect my ego, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Let $X$ denote the number of such earthquakes that occur in a year, and $Y$ the number of such traffic jams that occur in a given year. A natural choice for the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ is $\text{Poisson}(1)$ and $\text{Poisson}(1/25)$ respectively. You're looking to compute the probability of an event that can be described using the "arrival times" of the earthquakes and traffic jams whose distributions are known.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I'm not really sure what to do from here. How would I turn a Poisson distribution into my answer?